# Is there a name for a "when you do something, ..." phrase?

Tags: phrases, terminology, when

As in the title, is there a name for a phrase beginning "when something happens..." or "when someone does something...", and if so, what is it?

Comment: -1 research not shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependent clauses introduced by conjunctions such as *when*, *after*, *as soon as* are called **temporal clauses**. They are a subset of *adverbial clauses* that include *conditional clauses* (if, unless) and *concessive clauses* (although).